# How do I share common code between Rust projects without publishing to crates.io?

Tags: rust, rust-crates

There may not be a good answer for this question, but I have code that I would like to share between two different Rust projects **WITHOUT** publishing the crate to crates.io.

The code is proprietary and I don't want to put it out into the wild.

Comment: FYI, it appears this is a nice case of the [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/281829). It seems you *really* want to know "how do I share code without publicly publishing the common code", but the question is about a solution; one that technically precludes my answer from being acceptable. I took a gamble that it actually solves your root problem. ^_^

Comment: I may make sense to review the question, to make it match its intent more closely.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean @MatthieuM. This is definitely one way to do it. I suppose it won't work on **any** box since it is dependent on having the local crate, but it works in the local sense.

Comment: @mattforni: I mean that the question is more about "not publishing to crates.io" than "not creating a crate" so it would be better to focus it on the "not publishing to crates.io" bit; then answers can focus on how to distribute a crate internally within a company, which is really what you want to solve, rather than launch themselves in some kind of remote-syncing of copy/pasted files or such silliness :)

Comment: Check out the rewording I applied to your question, I think that's what @MatthieuM. and I are suggesting. Feel free to roll it back if you think it no longer matches your original intent.

Comment: @Shepmaster: That's indeed what I was thinking of too; now the question will probably be of interest to a much wider audience as I imagine that many organizations would rather not expose their code on Internet.

Comment: I like. Thanks guys. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> but it's proprietary code and I don't want to put it out into the wild.

You don't have to **publish** a crate. Specifically, just create the crate (`cargo new shared_stuff`) then specify the path to the common crate(s) in the dependent project's `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependency.shared_stuff]
path = "path/to/shared/crate"
```

The [Cargo documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html) has an entire section on types of dependencies:

- [Specifying dependencies from crates.io](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-cratesio)
- [Specifying dependencies from git repositories](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories)
- [Specifying path dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies)

I believe that Cargo will allow you to fetch from a **private** git repository (such as on Github or another privately hosted service, such as GitLab), but I haven't tried that personally. Based on my searching, you will need to have previously authenticated or otherwise configured git to not require an interactive password entry.

---

It's theoretically possible to create your **own** crate registry. I've not even attempted to do this, but the machinery is present in Cargo to handle it.